# Python XOR operation

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want XOR of characters but getting Type error:

sign value is - `\xc5\x06\x92\xd0\x02k=\x91`

How do I solve this?

```py
def xor(str1, str2):
    print(str1)
    print(str2)
    for i, j in zip(str1, str2):
        value[i] = chr(ord(str[i]) ^ ord(str[j]))  # Doing character by character XOR here
    return value


user = xor("admin\00\00\00", sig)
print(user)
```

Getting Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "exploit.py", line 36, in <module>
    username2 = xor("rator\00\00\00", signature1)
  File "exploit.py", line 32, in xor
    value[i] = chr(ord(str[i]) ^ ord(str[j]))
TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: You changed the question in the way that produces a _different_ error. Please don't do that, it looks like one of those Reddit threads with "Post a question, wait till I answer, then edit the question so it makes me look silly".

Comment: Not to mention the edit still has a traceback for the original error, not the one you'd see for the new version of the code.

Answer (score 0):

This statement `chr(ord(str[i]) ^ ord(str[j]))` is indexing the built-in function `str`, causing the error.

Comment: It was by mistake copied like that, corrected, same error still

Comment: @ShadowRanger has shown the correct way to write this.

Answer (score 0):

As [GZ0 notes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58090873/364696), you tried to index `str` itself (the type), not `str1` or `str2` (your arguments).

As it happens, you don't need to index at all; you're already iterating the characters themselves, so all you need to do is actually declare `value`, and use `i` and `j` directly:

```
    value = []
    for i, j in zip(str1, str2):
        value.append(chr(ord(i) ^ ord(j)))  # Doing character by character XOR here
    return ''.join(value)
```

Answer (score 0):

value = []
    for i, j in zip(str1, str2):
        value.append(chr(ord(i) ^ ord(j)))  # Doing character by character XOR here
    return ''.join(value)

As @ShadowRanger showed above, this worked